# Convert MS-Access to Sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2013

can I convert from **MS-Access** ( all tables,all forms,all reports,vba codes,...) to **Sharepoint**? I must create some portal app.first I tried in access then convert it to **Sharepoint**. i want to know is possible just convert it from ms access to **Sharepoint**?

Comment: You could start by Googling.  I did a quick search and found lots of information.

Comment: The short answer is no, there's isn't something available as far as I'm aware that converts all elements of an Access desktop database to SharePoint. You can create an Access web app using Access 2013 + Office 365 or SharePoint 2013 + Access Services. You can import your data into the web app and then link to the data and still use your rich Access front end file.